# Audience Scoped Announcements or List Items

Tags: audiences, scopedisplaygroup

Running SharePoint 2010 Ent, August 2011 CUs. We have an announcements list which when attempting to scope the list items to an audience, the audience scoping for that item seems to have no effect. The audience scoping for the web part is fine but any attempt to scope an individual item does not seem to. Scenario:

If you logon to the portal and post an announcement for staff only (audience targeted announcement) , if a student logs on, they too see the announcement.

Is there some kind of permissions that are overriding the audience scoping from working here or are we looking at some kind of bug in the August 2011 CU. The web part itself that shows the announcements list has no audience scoping.

We are also seeing the issue reported by Cyberpine in his question: [Navigation Audience - no exact match was found](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22294/navigation-audience-no-exact-match-was-found)

Comment: which web part you are using to display the announcements?

Comment: It is the native annoucements web part which is of type: XsltListViewWebPart

Comment: Could well be that it needs to be filtered using a CQWP:  http://techgrrl.wordpress.com/2010/05/13/audience-targeting-in-sharepoint-2010/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that you are using a webpart which supports item 
Evel audience and you enable item level audience target in the web part. For example the content query web part.

Comment: Tks Ashish, I created a CQWP for the announcments list which applies the filtering. The downside is to have to edit the Itemstyle.xlst file to show the body of the announcment properly.